# How do I package my C# code into standalone executables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package, exe, executable

Is there any way to package a C# project that am working on in Visual Studio 2015 Community into a stand-alone executable that doesn't need any other files or VS/.NET dependencies? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to have an application or a library that you can link to?  I think a little more elaboration is required.  Most of your System.* libraries are part of the .NET framework so you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: I'm looking to simply have a .EXE application instead of a VS folder with bin, obj etc in it.

Answer (score 0):

Build your project in release and you can use the output exe from bin/Release folder as a standalone executable.

If it has dependencies on assemblies which are not part of .NET framework you also need to merge all referenced dll assemblies into one exe file using [ilmerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630).

In both cases, users needs to have .NET framework installed on their machine.

Comment: ilmerge still has the .net framework dependencies that need to be installed on the system.

Comment: ilmerge is deprecated and no longer maintained

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an application with .net, it will always need the .net dependencies.  Depending on any libraries that you use, you will need them as dependencies as well.  If you truly want a native single exe than there are some third party vendors that can do this.  They make virtual applications that package the dependencies inside of the exe.  They are not free and I have not had good luck with these, but worth a shot.

One example https://turbo.net/studio

Answer (score 0):

The bin, obj, properties, etc. directories are part of your source code project not your executable. To exe application gets created in the bin directory. If you build it in debug mode, you'll find it in the bin\Debug folder. If you build it in release mode, you will find it in the bin'Release directory, etc.

That exe file should be good to run in any other computer.